# How to convert nested JSON data to a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nested

Here is the JSON data I currently have, which I need in a Pandas dataframe in order to use the data to my needs.

```
{
  "lab1": {
    "co2": [
      9.559335530495726
    ],
    "occupancy": [
      4
    ],
    "temperature": [
      21.033629524242304
    ],
    "time": "2020-09-15T16:15:35.565629"
  }
}
{
  "class1": {
    "co2": [
      24.168445969175817
    ],
    "occupancy": [
      15
    ],
    "temperature": [
      26.176607611778156
    ],
    "time": "2020-09-15T16:15:36.027525"
  }
}
{
  "office": {
    "co2": [
      6.633787232630541
    ],
    "occupancy": [
      1
    ],
    "temperature": [
      27.727982558797844
    ],
    "time": "2020-09-15T16:15:36.608386"
  }
}
```

I tried `json_normalize` but I couldn't understand how to normalize my JSON data.

```
with open('data.json','r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    # Normalizing data
    data1 = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['Results'])
    # Saving to CSV format 
    multiple_level_data.to_csv('multiplelevel_normalized_data.csv', index=False)
```

I use this code, the following error comes up

> JSONDecodeError Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in  1 with
> open('data.json','r') as f: ----> 2 data = json.loads(f.read())
> JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 14 column 2 (char 240)

Comment: Please add a minimal snippet of what you tried with json_normalize and add some details on how it doesn't fit your expectations (do you get errors ? which ones ? etc.)

Comment: `with open('data.json','r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
# Normalizing data
data1 = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['Results'])
# Saving to CSV format
multiple_level_data.to_csv('multiplelevel_normalized_data.csv', index=False)`
I use this code, the following error comes up

JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c65c487e9fed> in <module>
      1 with open('data.json','r') as f:
----> 2     data = json.loads(f.read())

JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 14 column 2 (char 240)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Fareed Ahmad posted a larger data set.

First, we create two functions: 1) convert the Gist file to a sequence of packets; and 2) convert a packet to a data frame:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import requests

def resp_to_packets(resp_text):
    ''' Convert file to list of packets.'''
    packet = ''
    for line in resp_text.split('\n'):
        if line.startswith('}{'):
            packet += '}'
            yield json.loads(packet)
            packet = '{'
        else:
            packet += line + '\n'
    yield json.loads(packet)

    
def packet_to_df(packet):
    ''' Convert packet to data frame.'''
    df = list()
    for key, values in packet.items():
        t = (pd.json_normalize(values)
              .explode('co2')
              .explode('occupancy')
              .explode('temperature')
              .assign(location=key)
             )
        df.append(t)
    return pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)

dtypes = {'co2': float, 'occupancy': int, 'temperature': float, 
          'time': 'datetime64', 'location': str}
```

Second, run the pipeline, which includes concatenating the data frames and converting types:

```
url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Fareed99/45b8a39a7e4493243ec973fa73f2b92b/raw/4b2eb95c24c95d40733f06d13dbf0356c4520e99/data.json'
r = requests.get(url)
assert r.ok

packets = (packet for packet in resp_to_packets(r.text))
dfs     = (packet_to_df(packet) for packet in packets)
df      = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True).astype(dtype=dtypes)

print(df.tail())

           co2  occupancy  temperature                       time location
476  45.237285         15    27.364173 2020-09-15 20:37:29.252201   class1
477   5.565177          4    21.033565 2020-09-15 20:37:29.667347     lab1
478  10.799228          1    21.014435 2020-09-15 20:37:30.689885     lab1
479  36.989700         20    27.059197 2020-09-15 20:37:33.467733   class1
480   1.836340          2    23.021893 2020-09-15 20:37:35.853943   office
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas read_json.

First remove all the '[' and ']' from the data using regex. Then convert it into a json file.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_json (r'Path where you saved the JSON file/filename.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach without regular expressions.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {'lab1': {'co2': [9.559335530495726],
              'occupancy': [4],
              'temperature': [21.033629524242304],
              'time': '2020-09-15T16:15:35.565629'}},
    {'class1': {'co2': [24.168445969175817],
                'occupancy': [15],
                'temperature': [26.176607611778156],
                'time': '2020-09-15T16:15:36.027525'}},
    {'office': {'co2': [6.633787232630541],
                'occupancy': [1],
                'temperature': [27.727982558797844],
                'time': '2020-09-15T16:15:36.608386'}}
]
```

Now iterate over the list of dictionaries.  Use `explode()` to flatten the lists.

```
df = list()
for d in data:
    for key, values in d.items():
        t = (pd.json_normalize(values)
              .explode('co2')
              .explode('occupancy')
              .explode('temperature')
              .assign(location=key)
             )
        df.append(t)

df = pd.concat(df)
print(df)

       co2 occupancy temperature                        time location
0  9.55934         4     21.0336  2020-09-15T16:15:35.565629     lab1
0  24.1684        15     26.1766  2020-09-15T16:15:36.027525   class1
0  6.63379         1      27.728  2020-09-15T16:15:36.608386   office
```

The original question does not have expected results, but this data frame would support many types of further analysis.

Comment: Thank you @jsmart for a prompt response, this worked very well for a given number of data packets but what if I want to read a json file with 1000s of data packets?
I tried to use `json.loads()` but I got to know that it can't load multiple object json data (which is the format of my data), how can I work around this problem?

Comment: IIUC, you could write Python code to 'flatten' the larger number of data packets, and convert the result to a data frame.  Could you post an example with a larger number of packets?

Comment: I guess we can't upload a .json file here in the comment. Just like I posted 3 data packets before, one for lab1, one for class1 and one for office. Similarly, for these three locations there will be multiple number of packets with different values but in the same format that i provided.
If you can give me your email I can send you the .json file for better understanding. @jsmart

Comment: Can you post a gist instead?  This makes it available to the SO community: https://gist.github.com

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Fareed99/45b8a39a7e4493243ec973fa73f2b92b
Here is the gist @jsmart